# How to stop logs filling with "multipath: sdc: can't store path info"

Tags: log, sd-card, logs, multipath

Tried

```
multipath -v2 -d
```

so I can find laptop's integrated card reader `wwid` and blacklist it (it's /dev/sdc), but nothing returned, just a new line

Any ideas how to stop `sdc: can't store path info` to fill logs?

Comment: Look at the logs. Read `man journalctl`, `sudo journalctl  -b 0 /dev/sdc`.

Comment: `journalctl -b 0 /dev/sdc` only shows general information about `Generic- Multi-Card`, `serial number`, `ums-realtek 2-1.6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected` and similar things. No errors or something that could help me to safely disable it without doing that through BIOS (if it's possible)